# MVC5 Identity Clicking on Register button does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

This is a MVC 5 Entity Framework with Identity web application. I'm trying to fix my register method which will create my users. When I click register nothing happens and I don't have any errors at all. I don't even know where to start looking for a solution.

I want the following properties as shown in the image to

[image]

AccountsViewModel.cs

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public int DepotID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepotList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepartmentList { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

}
```

AccountController.cs

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public AccountController()       
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
        ConfigureRegisterViewModel(model);
        ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName");
        ViewBag.DepotID = new SelectList(db.Depots, "DepotID", "DepotName");
        return View(model);
    }
    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ConfigureRegisterViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var user = new ApplicationUser() {
                UserName = model.UserName,
                Email = model.Email,
                FirstMidName = model.FirstMidName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                EnrollmentDate = model.EnrollmentDate,
                DepotID = model.DepotID,
                DepartmentID = model.DepartmentID
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
                return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    private void ConfigureRegisterViewModel(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        IEnumerable<Department> departments = db.Departments.OrderBy(u => u.DepartmentName);
        model.DepotList = departments.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.DepartmentID.ToString(),
            Text = a.DepartmentName.ToString()
        });
        IEnumerable<Depot> depots = db.Depots.OrderBy(u => u.DepotName);
        model.DepotList = depots.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.DepotID.ToString(),
            Text = a.DepotName.ToString()
        });
    }
```

}

Register.cshtml

```
model RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstMidName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstMidName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EnrollmentDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnrollmentDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>


            <div class="editor-field">
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DepotID, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DepotID, Model.DepotList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DepartmentID, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DepartmentID, Model.DepartmentList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                }
            </div>




            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
                </div>
            </div>
            }

            @section Scripts {
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code and ه noticed your problem.
You use two `@using (Html.BeginForm(..))`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

and

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

and both of them post back to Register action.this is not correct.

You don't need second `@using (Html.BeginForm())` delete it.

Comment: @TykiMikk Please upvote this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer from your point of view and helps them.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Register.cshtml` it appears that you may have inadvertently nested forms.

Somewhere in the markup you have `@using (Html.BeginForm())` which is nested inside them main form.

Removing the nesting might solve the issue.